# Cambiar raíz de $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, web, migration

Seguramente estoy preguntando una tontería... Hay alguna manera de cambiar la raíz a la que lleva *DOCUMENT_ROOT* ej: si lleva a /www que lleve a /www/2web

Mi intención es meter una web que tengo ya hecha en una subcarpeta "2web" y claro todos los archivos (muchos) utilizan $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] con lo que me estaré horas para buscar archivo por archivo

Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo para que todos los archivos enlacen bien "img,css, scripts etc..."?

Comment: ¿Qué servidor web usas? Eso se configura en él y sin saber cuál es no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy con dinahosting

Comment: ¿Alojamiento web, de servidor, VPS? Si es alojamiento web, es probable que eso debas hacerlo en su panel de control, consultando la ayuda de su web o contactando con su soporte técnico.

Comment: Hola, aunque no va directo a la mejor solución, actualmente herramientas como Netbeans permiten reemplazar en todo un proyecto una cadena. Es decir que podrías reemplazar $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] por la cadena que necesites. Saludos.